# Might there be a way to install cntk on winx32 architecture?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, cntk

I am trying to install microsoft **CNTK** in anaconda environment. I've already looked at the documentation of **cntk**, and there seem to be no way to use it on a **winx32** architecture. I am wondering if there is a way to do it. 
 Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, you cannot make it for x86/32bit windows. Only x64 windows/linux are supported